# Port 22 Filtered - Cannot determine cause

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

Sorry about the really basic question. I have Windows 10 with cygwin set up with openssh and the application allowed by my firewall. I am trying to set up the keypair but cannot connect to the host. The host has ssh enabled by default.

Tried turning off firewall, have tried using two different network connections (mobile hotspot and home network).

This may be a clue? The first and only time I connected was with Cygwin early yesterday, it did initially connect but at the password prompt even though I entered pwd correctly it denied access and disconnected. Since then I have only had timeouts....except for one other time, the first time I tried with PuTTy instead of Cygwin and same thing happened.

No problem pinging:

```
$ ping  ***.***.***.*

Pinging ***.***.***.* with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ***.***.***.*: bytes=32 time=171ms TTL=58
Reply from ***.***.***.*: bytes=32 time=283ms TTL=58
Reply from ***.***.***.*: bytes=32 time=115ms TTL=58
Reply from ***.***.***.*: bytes=32 time=123ms TTL=58

Ping statistics for ***.***.***.*:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 115ms, Maximum = 283ms, Average = 173ms
```

I have also tried connecting via IP but same result, my host has also confirmed user@ is not required, just the IP or domain.

When I try to connect to my host I get an error:

```
$ ssh -vvv www.domain.com.au
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "www.domain.com.au" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to www.domain.com.au [***.***.***.*] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ***.***.***.* port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host www.domain.com.au port 22: Connection timed out
```

However I can connect to other hosts no problem.

Here is the nmap port info:

```
`$ nmap www.domain.com.au

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( httpsnmap.org ) at 2017-07-02 10:45 tra
Nmap scan report for www.domain.com.au (***.***.***.*)
Host is up (0.11s latency).
rDNS record for ***.***.***.*: server-2-r57.ipv4.au.syrahost.com
Not shown: 976 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
20/tcp    closed ftp-data
21/tcp    open   ftp
25/tcp    open   smtp
80/tcp    open   http
110/tcp   open   pop3
143/tcp   open   imap
443/tcp   open   https
465/tcp   open   smtps
587/tcp   open   submission
993/tcp   open   imaps
995/tcp   open   pop3s
3306/tcp  open   mysql
5000/tcp  open   upnp
10000/tcp closed snet-sensor-mgmt
10001/tcp closed scp-config
10002/tcp closed documentum
10003/tcp closed documentum_s
10004/tcp closed emcrmirccd
10009/tcp closed swdtp-sv
10010/tcp closed rxapi
10012/tcp closed unknown
10024/tcp closed unknown
10025/tcp closed unknown
10082/tcp closed amandaidx

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.10 seconds.
```

Any ideas how I can debug this? My IP is not blocked and I can connect to the domain via FTP on port 21 no worries.

Debugging: SSH to localhost

```
$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jpols/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'jpols'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:wywfb93uyAAcCFJeZ/68LZvn2Ym26v+0k7Ii3OAfrMc
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256vn2Ym26v+0k7Ii3OAfrMc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Debugging: Telnet to remote

```
$ telnet domain.com.au 22
Trying ***.***.***.*...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Debugging:

Tried changing `sshd_config` port to `2222`. No luck, back using `22` again now.

Debugging: Nmap Traceroute

```
jpols@MrComputer ~
$ nMAP --traceroute -Pn -p 22 www.domain.com.au

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-03 14:56 tra
Nmap scan report for www.domain.com.au (***.***.***.*)
Host is up (0.047s latency).
rDNS record for ***.***.***.*: server-2-r57.ipv4.au.syrahost.com
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

TRACEROUTE (using proto 1/icmp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   0.00 ms  ***.***.*.*
2   32.00 ms ***.**.***.5
3   32.00 ms 097.pth0304.pth.iprimus.net.au (***.***.***.**)
4   32.00 ms ae1.csr01.mlganxd.wa.m2core.net.au (***.***.116.57)
5   32.00 ms ae5.csr01.prthpri.wa.m2core.net.au (***.***.116.49)
6   47.00 ms xe-0-2-0-21.pthpe01.pth.m2core.net.au (***.**.207.70)
7   32.00 ms ten-2-0-4.bdr01.per05.wa.vocus.net.au (***.**.207.208)
8   32.00 ms ten-0-0-0-1.cor02.per02.wa.vocus.net.au (***.**.206.38)
9   32.00 ms ge-0-0-3.bdr02.per02.wa.VOCUS.net.au (***.**.206.95)
10  ... 11
12  32.00 ms server-2-r57.ipv4.au.syrahost.com (***.***.***.*)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.38 seconds
```

The output above shows port 22 as filtered, my router and pc firewalls are temporarily disabled, anyone know how to debug the source of the filter?

Not sure if this is the right way to check but my external IP is showing port 22 open with a checker tool but my devices static IP is showing closed, is it accurate using a tool for the internal (device) ip? I'm at my wits end here but not giving up, the router has a rule setting port 22 as open for the device...what more can I do? See image:

[router rule to open ssh (port 22)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRZc4.png)

Image Showing firewall status

[Firewall Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5He4l.png)

Debugging: Note that since I posted this issue I have changed routers and internet service from ADSL to Fibre but still experiencing the same issue.

Have added inbound/outbound rules to allow port 22 in firewall just in case, no change.

Debugging: Traceroute

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      WinMTR statistics                                   |
|                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
|------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|                             ***.***.*.* -    0 |   66 |   66 |    1 |    3 |   25 |    3 |
|                           ***.**.***.5 -    0 |   66 |   66 |   12 |   15 |   37 |   16 |
|          097.pth0304.pth.iprimus.net.au -    0 |   65 |   65 |   12 |   15 |   31 |   17 |
|      ae1.csr01.mlganxd.wa.m2core.net.au -    0 |   66 |   66 |   13 |   16 |   38 |   14 |
|      ae5.csr01.prthpri.wa.m2core.net.au -    0 |   66 |   66 |   13 |   17 |   44 |   17 |
|   xe-0-2-0-21.pthpe01.pth.m2core.net.au -    0 |   65 |   65 |   13 |   16 |   36 |   15 |
|   ten-2-0-4.bdr01.per05.wa.vocus.net.au -    0 |   66 |   66 |   13 |   15 |   37 |   13 |
| ten-0-0-0-1.cor02.per02.wa.vocus.net.au -    0 |   66 |   66 |   13 |   16 |   46 |   14 |
|    ge-0-0-3.bdr02.per02.wa.VOCUS.net.au -    0 |   65 |   65 |   13 |   15 |   31 |   15 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |   13 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                   No response from host -  100 |   13 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|       ******-***.ipv4.au.****host.com -    0 |   65 |   65 |   13 |   16 |   40 |   19 |
|________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|
   WinMTR v0.92 GPL V2 by Appnor MSP - Fully Managed Hosting & Cloud Provider
```

Comment: The firewall protecting the remote host (www.nookdigitalmarketing.com.au) needs to allow in the connection on port 22. This shouldn't be an issue on your side router/firewall...

edit: ok ignore above - I can telnet to port 22 for that site, so looks to be fine. As an side, you should probably redact actual domain names etc.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, this has got me stumped. Not sure what else I can do at this point!

Comment: have you tried connecting to IP address instead of DNS name? Will help rule out any DNS issues...

Comment: No luck with just IP, funny thing is, it's morning here now and it seems once a day I am prompted for a password but even though I enter it correctly I am denied and after that it just times out.

Comment: is it possible your account is locked out, after a certain number of attempts? your IP could then be blocked for 24 hours, or similar...

Comment: I literally just got off the phone and confirmed my IP is not blocked. Waiting for their tier two support but it may take days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue and am annoyed to say that the host was blocking me the whole time even though the said they weren't. It took tier two support to fix (actually check??).

Thanks for all the help guys, gonna leave this here as it extensively details different debugging approaches for SSH with windows and Cygwin that may prove useful to someone in the future.